# Stopping rule for chi-squared discretization algorithm

Tags: chi-squared-test, discrete-data, optimal-stopping

I developed an algorithm that uses the chi-squared test to perform supervised discretization of a continuous variable. I described it in the paper "ChiD-A Chi-Squared Discretization Algorithm" published in the WUSS 2011 Proceedings available at  http://www.wuss.org/proceedings11/

The stopping criterion is not very intelligent, and I would like to know if there are better ways of stopping the discretization process.

Comment: Hmm. They really should try to come up with a different name for that conference.